# adding EventListeners in for-loop dosen't work

Tags: javascript, class, for-loop, event-listener

i got an basic class, in the constructor i create all necessary elements, also i got an Array with different informations and pictures.

For each entrie in the Array i create an  Element, and add a "click" event to these.
because i am looping through the Array, i can use propertys for the div from the array, it work's fine. The Eventlistener instead isn't working fine, for testpurpose i am logging the counter (i) when i click a div, the result is always 39 at each div, but i only got 38 entries in my Array.

i tried to outsource the process of adding eventlisteners in an different function, still the same result. Here's my code.

```
const models = [{name: "Hiker", sex: "female", modelHash: "a_f_y_hiker_01", url: "./create/pictures/models/93px-A_f_y_hiker_01.png"},
                    {name: "Downhill", sex: "male", modelHash: "a_m_y_dhill_01", url: "./create/pictures/models/93px-A_m_y_dhill_01.png"},
                    {name: "Ashley", sex: "female", modelHash: "cs_ashley", url: "./create/pictures/models/93px-Cs_ashley.png"},
                    {name: "Metzger", sex: "male", modelHash: "csb_chef2", url: "./create/pictures/models/93px-Csb_chef2.png"},
                    {name: "Hausmeister", sex: "male", modelHash: "csb_janitor", url: "./create/pictures/models/93px-Csb_janitor.png"},
                    {name: "Merryweather", sex: "male", modelHash: "csb_mweather", url: "./create/pictures/models/93px-Csb_mweather.png"},
                    {name: "Marine", sex: "male", modelHash: "csb_ramp_marine", url: "./create/pictures/models/93px-Csb_ramp_marine.png"},
                    {name: "Mexicaner", sex: "male", modelHash: "csb_ramp_mex", url: "./create/pictures/models/93px-Csb_ramp_mex.png"},
                    {name: "Vincent", sex: "male", modelHash: "csb_vincent", url: "./create/pictures/models/93px-Csb_vincent.png"},
```

[...]

```
for (var i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        this.chooseModelModelContainer = document.createElement("div");
        this.chooseModelModelContainer.classList.add("modelContainer");
        this.image = document.createElement("img");
        this.image.setAttribute("src", models[i].url);
        this.chooseModelModelContainer.append(this.image);
        this.chooseModelModelContainer.append(document.createTextNode(models[i].name));
        this.chooseModelBottomContainer.appendChild(this.chooseModelModelContainer);
        this.chooseModelModelContainer.addEventListener("click", (e, model)=>{
            console.log(i);
            //model = models[i].modelHash;
            //alt.emit("chooseModel:selected", model);
        });
```

the output is always 39 (got 38 entries) on each div.

i don't think it's because i am doing this in the constructor, becaus when i create a variable and select every element by class name and do the same thing in a different function, i got the same issue.

any idea how to fix this issue ?

Greetings

Comment: try `for (let i = 0; ...` instead of `for (var i = 0; ...`. The problem is that  `var` is not block scoped, so in your event handlers `i` will always point to the final value of the for-loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/1967864

Comment: @Đinh Carabus the final value of the for-loop ought to be the length of the array (38) but the question states the log result is 39. I have no idea why this matters as I assume the purpose of the log is just to check the `onclick` attribute fires, but it is curious and the only explanation I can think of is that at some point after the loop, i is incremented or, the array actually contains 39 items.